# Softlayer Concepts need to be clarified

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We need a few concepts to be clarified.

(1) What's the difference between SoftLayer_Hardware and SoftLayer_Hardware_Server?

(2) How can I figure out which virtual host my virtual guest stays? Further, how do we know all the virtual hosts information under our account? In most cases, we get a returned null from querying the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getHost method.

(3) SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag has a description like this: "When true this flag specifies that a compute instance is to run on hosts that only have guests from the same account." However, when we raised this question up in a Softlayer ticket, we got response that this flag sounds like setting dedicated CPUs, instead of dedicated hosts. We need clarification as to what this flag really means. By the way, we created an autoscale group with this parameters as "true", but we get null when we use the getHost method for the virtual guest, so what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**
[SoftLayer_Hardware](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware) is a service for many kind of hardware, for example: Gateways, Baremetals, etc. [SoftLayer_Hardware_Server](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server) is a service which is taking care of Bare Metal Servers.

**Question 2:**
The Host information is not available for customers, this information is only for employees or SoftLayer.

**Question 3:**
There is not an issue, the servers will be run on hosts with instances from the same account, as I told in question2, the host information is not available for customers, my apologizes for the inconveniences

Comment: Question 3: Can we also guarantee that the virtual guests not only running on virtual hosts from the same account, but also the virtual hosts running on bare metal servers (hardware servers) of the same account? By the way, you didn't clarify why they mentioned dedicated CPU not having an issue. Apparently you are referring to HOST instead of CPU.

Comment: The flag means dedicated host, not CPU

Comment: The Virtual Hosts/Virtual Guests (That I supposed that you refer) don't run in the same servers (Bare Metal Servers) from your account. SoftLayer will use the same host (which is different from your servers from your account) for your virtual guests.

Comment: My comments are added above as an answer due to the character limit here. Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

We still need again to clarify two other concepts here. From what I saw in the Softlayer REST API, our understanding is as follows.

(1) Virtual Guests (SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest) are the actual virtual machines. Since SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getHost points to a SoftLayer_Virtual_Host, therefore we believe

(2) Virtual Guests reside on Virtual Hosts (SoftLayer_Virtual_Host). Virtual Host is the concept we are not so clear.  But since SoftLayer_Virtual_Host::getHardware points to SoftLayer_Hardware_Server, therefore we believe

(3) Virtual Hosts reside on Hardware Servers (SoftLayer_Hardware_Server) . This SoftLayer_Hardware_Server sounds like a bare metal server. That's what I guess.

References:
[1] http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest

[2] http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Host

[3] http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server

So are all these correct?

Comment: The three points are correct, SoftLayer_Virtual_Host is the same SoftLayer_Hardware_Server in which the Virtual Guests reside.

Comment: The SoftLayer_Virtual_Host was created to show information about the relation between the VSIs (SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest) and the server in which it is located (SoftLayer_Hardware_Server)

Comment: I think the correct chain is SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest -> SoftLayer_Virtual_Host -> SoftLayer_Hardware_Server. SoftLayer_Virtual_Host is definitely different from SoftLayer_Hardware_Server from their REST API description.

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable now.